# CNAME to Amazon does not resolve

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services

I see a lot of people using IP addresses like,

```
ec2-54.208.90.77.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Just for reference, that's my actual instance IP address.

However, when I try I get,

```
$ nslookup ec2-54.208.90.77.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

** server can't find ec2-54.208.90.77.compute-1.amazonaws.com: NXDOMAIN
```

**`54.208.90.77`** is the actual EIP of my amazon instance. Why doesn't this work for me?

[There are quite a few place that suggest this should work.](https://serverfault.com/q/109845/18822)

Comment: I don't think it works for anyone else either.

Comment: I believe it should be "ec2-54-208-90-77.compute-1.amazonaws.com" instead of "ec2-54.208.90.77.compute-1.amazonaws.com".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be:

```
ec2-54-208-90-77.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

...which resolves correctly.

Additionally, that record is *not* a `CNAME`. It's an `A` record.

```
~  dig ec2-54-208-90-77.compute-1.amazonaws.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> ec2-54-208-90-77.compute-1.amazonaws.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 65412
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ec2-54-208-90-77.compute-1.amazonaws.com. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ec2-54-208-90-77.compute-1.amazonaws.com. 21599 IN A 54.208.90.77

;; Query time: 53 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.3.1#53(192.168.3.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Apr  7 13:18:57 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 74
```